# Heroes 3 using wine?

Tags: 12.10, wine

No matter how much I read I just can't understand how to get wine to work.

I'm trying to play Heroes 3. I currently have Wine 1.5.18 installed on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, and i have a rar file with the files from an installed copy of the heroes 3 game in it (not the installer).  This copy of the already-installed game has worked on every computer I tried after extracting, but I have no idea what to do with it on linux.

Comment: what does "(not install)" mean?  What is this file - is it the installer, or is it a copy of the installed game, or what?

Comment: @JimSalter It's a 写opy of the installed game.

Answer (score 0):

```
you@yourpc:~$ sudo apt-get install unrar-free
you@yourpc:~$ unrar-free heroes3.rar
```

You should now be able to browse into the folder created when you unrar'ed the file, and double-click the .EXE file for Heroes and have it open in Wine.